# Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I use IDEA develop my code, and in IDEA environment,the code runs well, but when I use mvn clean install to build the project ,and run the projet with this script

```
#!/bin/bash


source ~/.bashrc

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Drun_dir=$MY_ROOT"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xss256k -Xms1g -Xmx1g"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=4 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dclient.enczoding.override=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=zh -Duser.region=CN"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.ext.dirs=./lib -Djava.library.path=./lib -cp ./resources"

java $JAVA_OPTS Main
```

it comes the error

```
Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
```

jdk is the same version, anyone can help?

Comment: You changed `java.ext.dirs` from the default value, which includes (most of) the cryptoproviders, to a wrong value, so the cryptoproviders cannot be used. The default also includes `localedata.jar` and I'm pretty sure `zh-CN` is not in the basic part of the runtime so I'd expect i18n in your program to fail also, but perhaps silently. JRE expects `java.ext.dirs` to be used for the Java-defined extension mechanism and using it for anything else is likely to cause problems; the classpath is for user-written (or third-party) code.

Comment: thanks ,

`CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

for jar in `ls ./lib`
do
   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./lib/$jar;
done
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -cp ./resources"

java $JAVA_OPTS  -classpath $CLASSPATH Main`  I changed the script like this ,and it did work

Answer (score 0):

thanks [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) ,
change the script to

```
source ~/.bashrc

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

for jar in `ls ./lib`
do
   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./lib/$jar;
done
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./resources


JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xss256k -Xms1g -Xmx1g"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=4 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dclient.enczoding.override=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

java $JAVA_OPTS  -classpath $CLASSPATH Main
```

Comment: If your `lib/*`jars all have suffix `.jar` (or `.JAR`) and there aren't hidden files (beginning with dot), and since at least Java6 (I think 5 but can no longer verify), you can use `CLASSPATH=./lib/*:./resources` See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html under 'Understanding class path wildcards'.